# Kotlin compile from cli - unresolved reference

Tags: apache-spark, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin. My goal is to run spark functions written in Kotlin for Streaming and Transforming. I have downloaded the Kotlin native compiler and have written this simple spark function with vim:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

val conf = SparkConf()
        .setMaster("yarn")
        .setAppName("Kotlin Spark Test")

val sc = JavaSparkContext(conf)
}
```

I then save it as SparkApp.kt and run the compiler with the following command:

```
kotlinc SparkApp.kt -ib $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.3.1.jar -o SparkApp.jar
```

which spectacularly fails with errors:

> error: unresolved reference: org
>   and so on

Did I miss something?

Comment: What is the kotlin version? Btw you need to add `}` at the and to close function body.

Comment: What is the `-ib` flag?  My kotlinc doesn't seem to have it.  I'd suggest trying `-cp` instead — and putting that (and its jar file) _before_ the file you're compiling.

Comment: It's kotlin-native-linux-1.3.11, `-ib` is `-include-binary`, there is no `-include-runtime` or `-classpath`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JVM libraries as Kotlin/Native dependencies. Kotlin/Native can only use `*.klib` Kotlin libraries and inter-operate with native libraries by the means of the CInterop tool.

The JVM libraries can only be used by Kotlin/JVM, and neither Kotlin/JS nor Kotlin/Native can use the JVM bytecode libraries as dependencies.

If you want to compile the program for the JVM instead, then you are definitely using the wrong command line tool, as `kotlin-native-linux-...` is a Kotlin/Native compiler. Use either `kotlin-compiler-...` or `experimental-kotlin-compiler-linux-...` for Kotlin/JVM. And, of course, pass the JVM library as `-cp`, not `-ib`.

Comment: I've changed from native to experimental the error is still the same even with `kotlinc SparkApp.kt -cp $SPARK_HOME/jars -include-runtime -d SparkApp.jar`, any idea?